# GatsbyJS: create json/structured data from ACF repeater field

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create an ACF Repeater field which contains structured data. I then want to output the field in  of my GatsbyJS site. For this task, I am using React helmet.

My code:

```
      <Helmet>
        {wpPage.schemaMarkup.schemarepeater.map(
          (schemaJson, id) =>
            schemaJson !== null && (
              <script type="application/ld+json" key={id}>
                {JSON.stringify(schemaJson)}
              </script>
            )
        )}
      </Helmet>
```

My GraphQL Schema in template file:

```
wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      __typename
      id
      uri
      content
      title
      schemaMarkup {
        schemarepeater {
          schemaJson
        }
      }
    }
```

The code kinda works. The only issue is, that if a page doesn't contain a value (Not all pages should have value) in my ACF Repeater field it returns error: `WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`

I have tried with comparison with !== null but it didn't seem to solve issue.

Comment: That just returns error unexpected ","

Comment: `{wpPage.schemaMarkup.schemarepeater && wpPage.schemaMarkup.schemarepeater.map(`

Comment: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

Comment: Oh you're right.... It seems to have solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the availability of the fields first:

```
  <Helmet>
    {wpPage.schemaMarkup.schemarepeater && wpPage.schemaMarkup.schemarepeater.map(
      (schemaJson, id) =>
        schemaJson !== null && (
          <script type="application/ld+json" key={id}>
            {JSON.stringify(schemaJson)}
          </script>
        )
    )}
  </Helmet>
```